# Mount a folder from server in network on mn the local machine permanently

Tags: terminal, mount, cifs, file-server

I have a remote server which is connected to my wi-fi modem. So I can access this server by 192.158.188.45 I want to mount a folder from this server on my local machine permanently. I wrote

```
\\192.168.188.45\share  /mnt/buffalo  cifs  credentials=/home/l-one/Documents/credentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777  0  0
```

in my `/etc/fstab` file. Now I can mount this folder every time I type `sudo mount -a` But there's a problem. When I restart my computer I have to type this `sudo mount -a` again to mount it. So what do I make to mount it one time and forever. I typed `sudo mount -a` in the Startup Applications and in the `/etc/rc.local` but it did not help. What am I supposed to do ?

Comment: I have one  line exactly like yours, except it would be //192.168.188.45/share. My credentials are also in /root/creds. It is auto mounted on reboots.

Comment: yeah the share should be `//192.168.188.45/share` - not `\\192.168.188.45\share`